# General website technical security

Tags: security

When you have the following protections

- XSS protection
- SQL injection protection
- CSRF protection
- Session on serverside (database)
- Anti spam Captcha (+- effective)

What are the technical threats remaining, that I am not aware of, to be considered?

Also, how to help against attacks on the MAX specs of the machines (HDD spaces, max bandwith, max processor power, etc))

I understand that I can only limit one client's repetitive behaviours, but if that client is controling other clients then the threat scale horizontally and my protection is completly useless. Any way to deal with this?

Comment: Just looking at the [OWASP Top Ten](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project), there are seven items left that you might have missed yet. Besides these deliberate causes, there are also other causes like unintentional behavior or force majeure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have address less than half of the [OWASP TOP 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main).   Most importantly [Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4) and [insufficient transport layer protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9) because these are very commonly used by attackers. Also don't forget about [Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking).